File explorer functionality for DrRacket?
For me, adding the ability to browse files/directories to DrRacket would be a giant help.   I found a reference to the plugin, "files-viewer" but documentation links are broken. Can anyone offer how-to info on using this plugin or some other alternative?  Thanks!

https://racket.discourse.group/t/file-explorer-functionality-for-drracket/3037
